# "To be pound of something": Correct meaning and usage

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-usage

I came across an email mentioning : "We are pound to announce that .. (some good announcement)". Initially I thought it was a spelling mistake and they meant "proud" and not "pound". However, when I Googled, I saw many webpages having similar usage of "pound".

I understand the meaning of "pound" as a verb is to strike or to hit. However, I don't understand what's the meaning to this phrase: "to be pound of something".

What does it mean exactly? (and whether it's a correct usage at all)

Comment: I think that you have simply googled a common mistyping of the word proud or perhaps there is some auto-text correction program that converts a misspelling of proud into the word pound and people don't notice

Comment: There is no way that pound could be used in your example. Your initial thought is right.

Comment: In Google, there are about 876 results with phrase showing "pound", compared to about 10,600,000 with the phrase showing "proud". In for a penny, in for a proud.

Comment: Googling "to be pound of" suggests - Did you mean "to be proud of"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Pound* as a verb can also mean *to shut in, to trap*, though the more common verb is *impound*.

However neither meaning of the verb *pound* makes sense in this context. Looking at the first few results when I google "we are pound to", it is clear that the authors intended to write *proud*. As [Rolf of Saxony](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/137828/rolf-of-saxony) says above,

> "perhaps there is some auto-text correction program that converts a
>   misspelling of proud into the word pound and people don't notice".

There is also [this interesting case](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=RuNhAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA9&lpg=PA9&dq=%22We%20are%20pound%20to%22&source=bl&ots=BxznEByfSF&sig=WWIZfR_6c6Q-SNp_DQ0-Tbnubao&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj3-oD48-fKAhUD1x4KHaMYBusQ6AEIJzAC#v=onepage&q=%22We%20are%20pound%20to%22&f=false), where it appears that automatic character recognition has misread "we are bound to receive" (i.e. we are obliged) in the original printed text as "we are pound to receive".

Comment: That 'b' in your *interesting case* looks different from the one in the line above it. Dust, perhaps? It looks a little like the old letter [thorn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorn_%28letter%29).